# JSON MessageHeaders with headerMode=raw

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a Spring Cloud Stream (SCS) Kafka producing app configured with Sleuth for tracing. I'm trying to publish a spring-messaging 'GenericMessage' (i.e. MessageHeaders + payload) that needs to be consumed both by:

- SCS consumers (who should continue the trace which is automatically added to MessageHeaders)
- Non SCS/Java consumers who should just skip MessageHeaders and process the payload.

*With headerMode=embeddedHeaders (the default):*
The tracing entries in MessageHeader are prepended to the message by EmbeddedHeaderUtils before it is published. My non java consumers can't handle this as EmbeddedHeaderUtils doesn't serialize to pure JSON, i.e.

`?\n invalid-json-headers { payload }`

*With headerMode=raw:*
The MessageHeaders are not sent at all, only the payload is serialized.
i.e.
`{ payload }`

I really just want to publish the whole GenericMessage as it was created, including the trace + span IDs that Sleuth adds, i.e.:

`{"headers": {"id": "x", "trace": "y", "span": "z"}, "payload": { ... }}`

Is there any way to achieve this other than publishing to one topic for SCS consumers, and another with just the payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, publish that message as a `payload` of an outbound message:

```
return MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build();
```

This way your message will be serialized as a `payload` and you can access to the required headers after the proper deserialization and casting `payload` to the `Message`.

Comment: Kafka 0.11 supports headers natively; we are in the process of building a binder that supports that version so issues like this will go away.

Comment: thanks - i've settled with this for now. It's not perfect as now the GenericMessage is part of the payload, the tracing interceptors obviously don't work their magic and automatically add trace/span information to it's headers.

Comment: It does now however throw an exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token` thrown by MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal.

Comment: There is no other choice unless embed headers somehow for systems which don't support header - Kafka, AWS Kinesis. Not sure you have a problem with tracing, since all you need is to add one more `ChannelInterceptor` to wrap the message to the `payload` before sending to the `output`. And perform opposite operation when you receive message before sending to the `input`

Comment: That's correct the `GenericMessage` isn't compatible with the JSON by default. You should consider to use `JacksonJsonUtils.messagingAwareMapper()` since Spring Integration `4.3.10`. For example: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/redis.html#redis-message-store